# How to build the c library for tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I've been through the steps to build tensorflow and it's working in python.  Now how do I *BUILD* the C tensorflow library I want to use?

```
$ gcc -I../tensorflow -ltensorflow g.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltensorflow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To build the C library from source, follow most of the instructions [for building TensorFlow from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), except that instead of building the pip package, build the tarball that packages the shared libraries and C API header file:

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/lib_package:libtensorflow
```

This will produce a tarball in:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/lib_package/libtensorflow.tar.gz
```

More details in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/lib_package/README.md

The [release binaries](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c) are built using the process described above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks @ash .  but why it's recompiling core as well as jpeg and png code... i don't know.

Comment: Don't quite follow your comment

Comment: libtensorflow should have been mostly compiled when the pip package was built.  instead, bazel is busy compiling core as well as various unnecessary code.  it's a criticism of the tensorflow build process, not your answer.

Comment: I don't quite know what's happening in your setup, but in general `bazel` does cache build artifacts. Is it possible that the options you provided when building the pip package were different (e.g., enabling AVX2 or `-march=native` or something)?

Comment: nah - vanillla.  ie  ```bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package```.  back when make was standard, we called the artifacts of compiling "object files" :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 libraries you have to build:

- `libtensorflow_framework.so`
- `libtensorflow.so`

To build them you have to use bazel

```
bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.so
bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
```

Once the build process of both libraries ends, you have to make the linker aware of where these libraries are, hence you have to upgrade the  `LIBRARY_PATH` and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly.

```
TENSORFLOW_LIB = "/path/of/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${TENSORFLOW_LIB}`
export LIBRARY_PATH=${LIBRARY_PATH}:${TENSORFLOW_LIB}
```

Comment: do i need to link against both libraries to build an exe?

Comment: libtensorflow_framework.so appears to have been built by the libtensorflow.so target (nothing done for ```bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.so```)

Comment: You just need to let the linker aware of these libraries, the `-ltensorflow` flag will do the rest